# Firewall ports needed for Visual Studio 2013 Remote Debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2013, firewall, remote-debugging, ports

I have a 3rd party firewall blocking VS 2013 Update 2 Remote Debugging. I want our domain admin to open the necessary ports, but there seems to be a discrepancy in the documentation.

[Online version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0d7tte4%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) mentions:

> DCOM (TCP Port 135) and IPSEC (UDP 4500 / UDP 500)

Installed documentation mentions:

> ...To do so, allow traffic on TCP/IP ports that msvsmon.exe is listening on. By default, these are port 4018 and 4019, where 4018 is used on all operating systems, and 4019 is used only on Windows x64 to allow debugging x86 processes.

No mention of DCOM / IPSec. I know there was an architectural change starting Remote Tools 2012, but I don't know if it means that DCOM and IPSec were dropped since then. I've seen in the installed documentation mention of the Windows Web Services API, shipping with Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 (which happen to be my local/remote versions). Does this perhaps replace the DCOM and IPSec architecture?

Bottom line - which ports do I need to open for this particular version?

*Comment: Editors please do not remove the words "Update 2", the Remote Tools have different versions corresponding to the different Visual Studio 2013 versions.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently tested remote debugging with Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 to an AWS EC2 instance.

I only needed inbound security group rules for TCP 4018-4019.

(Previously with Visual Studio 2012 I only needed inbound security group rules for TCP 4016-4017.)

Comment: Apologies for not noticing your answer until now :) I'm marking it "accepted" even though I haven't tested it myself