# VS2013 Remote Debugging - Firewall preventing connection despite open ports

Tags: visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging, windows-server-2012, windows-firewall

I have a fairly large web application developed in Visual Studio 2013, working perfectly on my local IIS. I have deployed to my remote server (Windows Server 2012) and have the usual problems with adapting to remote vs. local. My main issue is I cannot remote debug out of VS2013. The message I get is this:

[Error Message from VS2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzgDT.png)

What I have tried so far:
As per [Firewall ports needed for Visual Studio 2013 Remote Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784857/firewall-ports-needed-for-visual-studio-2013-remote-debugging) I have opened both TCP 4018 and 4019. First inbound, then also outbound.

Since that did not work I also opened DCOM (TCP 135) and UDP 4500 and 500. I did not create a new DCOM rule, only enabled the existing ones.

A few things to note:
1. The correct version of Remote Debugging Tools for VS2013 is installed
2. The Debugger is running and waiting for a new connection (run as admin)
3. My local machine and the remote server are both on the same VPN using LogMeIn Hamachi
4. I can see the machine when I try to attach process in the VS2013 debug configuration, it just won't allow me to connect.

I am out of ideas here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See the required ports for remote debugging here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee126350(v=vs.100).aspx

```
[TCP] 135, 139, 445 - Required
[UDP] 137, 138 - Required
[UDP] 500, 4500 - Required if your domain policy requires network communication to be performed through IPSec.
[TCP] 80 - Required for Web Server debugging.
```

hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I have found that article and opened all relevant ports without success. I ended up installing VS on the server and I am debugging that way right now, which is not ideal but better than nothing. This remains a mystery to me.